# Compile java code created in IntelliJ in command line

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I created a java project in IntelliJ utilizing the .form interface for creating a GUI.

I need to send this code to a company as part of an interview process, so it needs to be easily compiled.

Is there a way to compile my code in command line with a .form file?

Comment: Are you sure that the .form is not translated in another java class? If it is translated you can create a ant script or a batch using javac / java

Comment: IntelliJ has the option to generate either class files or java source from the form, but I'm not sure how to compile the code using either.

Comment: usually with a ant script or a simple .batch file (for executing on windows cmd or linux bash) with the instructions for javac (for every file) and a java -classpath with the compiled files. You must search for it. If IntelliJ has a gradle file for the project, you can look how to run it from command line.

Comment: Would this be the correct syntax for adding the class files to the classpath assuming they are in a folder called ui? javac -g -d out -cp gson-2.6.2.jar;ui/* *.java